# Why does publish_{custom-post-type} fire on update?

Tags: publish, save-post

I'm trying to fire two different actions on both publish and update. Neither should ever fire at the same time.

The problem is that `publish_pm_task` is getting fired on update and `save_post` is never getting fired? See anything wrong with this?

```
<?php
// Updated task notification
add_action( 'save_post', 'pm_updated_task_notification' );

// New task notification
add_action( 'publish_pm_task', 'pm_new_task_notification' );

function pm_new_task_notification() {

    error_log('definitely a task');

}

function pm_updated_task_notification( $post_id ) {

    $slug = 'pm_task';

    /* check whether anything should be done */
    $_POST += array("{$slug}_edit_nonce" => '');
    if ($slug != $_POST['post_type']) {
        return;
    }
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return;
    }
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST["{$slug}_edit_nonce"], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
        return;
    }

    error_log('updated a task');

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you have to understand that when we update a post, `wp_update_post` function is called. But due to a bit not optimal design of WP core, the actual saving is processed by `wp_insert_post` function. See it in trac on [line 3006](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2968).

Ok, next lets see what is inside of `wp_insert_post` function. As you can see, on [line 2950](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2942), `save_post` action is called each time the function is called, whenever it has been called directly or by `wp_update_post` function. It means that it doesn't suit to determine if post has been inserted/published or updated.

To find better action, lets take a look at `wp_transition_post_status` function which is called almost just before `save_post` action, see it on [line 2942](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L2942). This function does three actions `transition_post_status`, `{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}` and `{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`, see it on [line 3273](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L3273). Here we have nice action `transition_post_status`, which passes old and new post statuses. This is what we need. So if new status is `publish` and old status is not `publish`, then the post is published. And if new status is `publish` and old status is `new`, then the post has been inserted. And finally if new status equals to old status, then the post has been just updated.

Here is your snippet:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_transition_post_status', 10, 3 );  

function wpse_transition_post_status( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status == 'new' ) {
        // the post is inserted
    } else if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' ) {
        // the post is published
    } else {
        // the post is updated
    }
}
```

P.S.: read the code of the WordPress core, each time when you in doubts, it will help you a lot!